# Hosting .Net Core Web API as Guest Service in Service Fabric

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, service-fabric-stateless, guest-executable

Hi Please can anyone help, I'm trying to get Service Fabric to Host a .Net Core Web API Restful service as a Guest Executable.

I'm guessing possibly incorrectly that I should be able to run the exe once I have done the full publish, but it fails when I do.

I have done the following...

1. Ensured the main Web API assembly and all referenced .NET Core assemblies are set to x64 Targets
2. Set the Output type to be an exe and have a program.cs as below...

   ```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var host = new WebHostBuilder()
           .UseKestrel()
           .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .UseIISIntegration()
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .UseApplicationInsights()
           .Build();

       host.Run();
   }
   ```
3. Done the command line stuff...

   ```
   dotnet restore
   dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64
   ```
4. Made a Referenced to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0"
   in Project.deps.json in the resultant win10-x64 publish folder.

However when I execute the thing directly the console window reports a problem with the StartUp Constructor, i.e. when performing builder.build.

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            //.AddServiceFabricConfig("Config") // Add Service Fabric configuration settings.
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

I feel close to getting this stuff working and have added a Service Fabric Guest Host project to host the exe, but needless to say the node fails with the error shown below...

```
Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='CodePackageActivation:Code:EntryPoint'.
```

There was an error during CodePackage activation.The service host terminated with exit code:2147516556

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you find any answer for this?

Comment: https://rahulrai.in/post/Deploying-Guest-Executables-to-Azure-Service-Fabric/ or https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/13/hosting-net-core-services-on-service-fabric/ looks like it might help you